# Make multiple-select to adjust its height to fit options without scroll bar

Tags: html, css, html-select

Apparently this doesn't work:

```
   select[multiple]{
     height: 100%;
   }
```

it makes the select have 100% page height...

`auto` doesn't work either, I still get the vertical scrollbar.

Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: I think you're stuck with using some javascript.  I don't believe there's a way to have a select box automatically stretch css-only to contain the contents.

Comment: Pure CSS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55969271/7910454

Answer (score 176):

I guess you can use the **`size`** attribute. It works in all recent browsers.

```html
<select name="courses" multiple="multiple" size="30" style="height: 100%;">
```

Comment: Hi, How is this different to what was stated in the question not to work?

Comment: Hi, it's different because it embodies the size attribute. The initial question only refers to the height attribute

Comment: Ah ok. It doesn't actually make the box shrink to the size of the contents, you have to manually set the number size value, which is fine if you know how many options there are but more of a problem if there is a dynamic number of options. In which case you would have to set resize the size attribute when you populated the box. I see now, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Oh, come on! If you are "populating" on the server, then you know how many there will be. And if you can "populate" using AJAX, modifying a modest attribute will be no challenge. You can even count the options in JS after "populating".

Comment: $('select.expandable').each(function() { $(this).attr('size', $(this).find('option').length) }) 
– Francesc Rosàs Sep 5 '12 at 16:43

A comment on another answer.

Comment: It worked, but also the height of <select> getting increased as per the size and as a result distorting my layout. ;( –

Comment: why do i got `invalid property value`? i wrote `size: 5;` in css, and selection has 5 fixed items.

Comment: @LeiYang it's an attribute of the select html tag, you can't add it to CSS.

Answer (score 72):

You can do this using the `size` attribute in the `select` tag.
Supposing you have 8 options, then you would do it like:

```
<select name='courses' multiple="multiple" size='8'>
```

Comment: It worked, but also the height of <select> getting increased as per the size and as a result distorting my layout. ;(

Comment: how to specify this value in css?

Answer (score 30):

Old, but this will do what you're after without need for jquery. The hidden overflow gets rid of the scrollbar, and the javascript makes it the right size.

```
<select multiple='multiple' id='select' style='overflow:hidden'>
<option value='foo'>foo</option>
<option value='bar'>bar</option>
<option value='abc'>abc</option>
<option value='def'>def</option>
<option value='xyz'>xyz</option>
</select>
```

And just a tiny amount of javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.size = select.length;
```

Answer (score 13):

For jQuery you can try this. I always do the following and it works.

```
$(function () {
   $("#multiSelect").attr("size",$("#multiSelect option").length);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

You can only do this in Javascript/JQuery, you can do it with the following JQuery (assuming you've gave your select an id of multiselect):

```
$(function () {
    $("#multiSelect").css("height", parseInt($("#multiSelect option").length) * 20);
});
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/AZEFU/

Comment: The same idea without relying on row height: `$('select.expandable').each(function() { $(this).attr('size', $(this).find('option').length) })`

Comment: @FrancescRosàs Perfect! Pity this is buried in a comment instead of being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

`select` could contain `optgroup` which takes one line each:

```
<select id="list">
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<script>
  const l = document.getElementById("list")
  l.setAttribute("size", l.childElementCount + l.length)
</script>
```

In this example total `size` is `(1+1)+(1+2)=5`.

Comment: Both the above answers are technically correct, but this is the more interesting answer.

Comment: I prefer this answer as I don't know how many items will appear in the list. But I only set:  l.setAttribute('size', l.childElementCount +1); _(not double the length as the code above shows)_

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is old, but how the topic is not closed I'll give my help.

The attribute "size" will resolve your problem.

Example:

```
<select name="courses" multiple="multiple" size="30">
```

Comment: Provided there are always 30 options in the select.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with simple javascript...

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="return this.length();">
```

...or limit height until number-of-records...

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="return this.length() > 10 ? this.length(): 10;">
```

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't work anymore. My work around is `$('#firstSelect').attr('size', $('#firstSelect').length);`.  Look at this fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/ergt5upf/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/ergt5upf/2/)

Answer (score 4):

To remove the scrollbar add the following CSS:

```
select[multiple] {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```css
select[multiple] {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select multiple size="3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can count option tag first, and then set the count for size attribute.
For example, in PHP you can count the array and then use a foreach loop for the array.

```
<?php $count = count($array); ?>
<select size="<?php echo $count; ?>" style="height:100%;">
<?php foreach ($array as $item){ ?>
    <option value="valueItem">Name Item</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the *size* attribute is the most practical solution, however there are quirks when it is applied to *select* elements with only two or three options.

- Setting the size attribute value to "0" or "1" will mostly render a default select element (dropdown).
- Setting the size attribute to a value greater than "1" will mostly render a selection list with a height capable of displaying at least four items. This also applies to lists with only two or three items, leading to unintended white-space.

Simple JavaScript can be used to set the *size* attribute to the correct value automatically, e.g. see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x1kzem0/).

```
$(function() {
    $("#autoheight").attr("size", parseInt($("#autoheight option").length)); 
});
```

As mentioned above, this solution does not solve the issue when there are only two or three options.

Comment: This solution requires jQuery and thus in my opinion is not "simple JavaScript". Also, this code has already been shown in earlier answers..

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the size (height) of all multiple selects to the number of options, use jQuery:

```
$('select[multiple = multiple]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('size', $(this).find('option').length)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

friends: 
if you retrieve de data from a DB: 
you can call this
 $registers =  *_num_rows( Result_query )
then

```
<select size=<?=$registers + 1; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this requirement recently and used other posts from this question to create this script:

```
$("select[multiple]").each(function() {
  $(this).css("height","100%")
    .attr("size",this.length);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The way a select box is rendered is determined by the browser itself. So every browser will show you the height of the option list box in another height.
You can't influence that.
The only way you can change that is to make an own select from the scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample package usage, which is quite popular in Laravel community:

```
{!! Form::select('subdomains[]', $subdomains, null, [
    'id' => 'subdomains',
    'multiple' => true,
    'size' => $subdomains->count(),
    'class' => 'col-12 col-md-4 form-control '.($errors->has('subdomains') ? 'is-invalid' : ''),
]) !!}
```

Package: https://laravelcollective.com/

Comment: That's not Laravel, that's a Laravel package.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I'm going to update the post.