# grails g:select increase size of multi-select box

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a multi-select box in one of my views that's been generated by the following line:

```
<f:all bean="testDomain1" />
```

Where my domain class has a hasMany of testDomain2.  In my test system, I have about 15 instances of testDomain2, and they show up just fine in the multi-select box.  My issue is that the box is only 4 lines, and my Windows is set to scroll 3 lines at a time from the scroll wheel.

When I scroll in this multi-select box, it skips over several entries, and I can only see them by clicking the scroll up and down buttons.  This is all very annoying, and could easily be solved if I could just change my multi-select box to be more than 4 lines.  I have plenty of screen space to work with, but I can't find any way to make  tag make a multi-select box that's 6, 8, or 10 lines long to address this.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make multiple-select to adjust its height to fit options without scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943886/make-multiple-select-to-adjust-its-height-to-fit-options-without-scroll-bar)

Comment: This is specifically in the context of a Grails tag, and not standard HTML