# Select Options height to auto

Tags: css

I would like to ask on how to make the select list height to auto. Because there's a large white space in the select list. please see [image: attached]

Here's my html code

```css
.form-select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-line;
  overflow-y: unset;
}

.form-select option {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.form-select option:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

.form-select select {
  text-align-last: center;
  padding-right: 29px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-keyword" multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" size="9"
  class="form-select" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="211">AI</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="186">Clean energy</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="196">COVID-19</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="201">Digitization</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="206">IoT</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="31">Keyword 2</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="226">LNG</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="191">Oil ＆Gas</option>
  <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="221">Power Plant</option>
</select>
```

I removed the option inside the select option.

Comment: your HTML is invalid. `<option>` cannot have `type=` or `Class=` attributes https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-option-element.html

Comment: You can try giving a max-height to your select .```.form-select select {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}```

Comment: Thanks for answering esQmo but still the height was not in auto

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers while @MisterJojo is spot on with `type` attributes being not allowed on `option` elements, the `class` attribute is allowed for ALL html elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/global-attributes.html#global-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The height is determined by the `size` attribute on your `select` element. `size` is determined by the number of list items you want visible as a vertical list. Setting it to `3` will give you three lines worth of height.

Additionally, as @Mister Jojo mentioned, use `submit` for when you're submitting your form. If you want to watch events on your `options`, [add an event listener to them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943886/make-multiple-select-to-adjust-its-height-to-fit-options-without-scroll-bar) also has some options for setting the `size` dynamically.

```css
.form-select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-line;
  overflow-y: unset;
  max-height: auto;
}

.form-select option {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.form-select option:hover {
  background: lightblue;
}

.form-select select {
  text-align-last: center;
  padding-right: 29px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <select multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" class="form-select" size="3">
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="211">AI</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="176">Carbon Capture</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="186">Clean energy</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="196">COVID-19</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="216">Digital Twins</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="201">Digitization</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="181">Energy Mix</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="26">Hydrogen</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="206">IoT</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="31" selected="selected">Keyword 2</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="226">LNG</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="191">Oil ＆Gas</option>
    <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="221">Power Plant</option>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you for answering but still the whitespace was not gone, I already remove the type inside the option but still display still the same

Comment: Did you update the size value?

Comment: yes, when if there's a one line in the select option there still a white space

Comment: <select data-drupal-selector="edit-keyword" multiple="multiple" name="keyword[]" id="edit-keyword" class="form-select"
                      onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
                      <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="251">Ammonia</option>
                      <option class="filter-item br-8 f-14-med" value="253">Automation</option>
                    </select>

Comment: In that example your `select` doesn't have a `size` attribute. Try adding `size="3"` to it